# How to cut wide shallow grooves in existing driveway slab

Tags: concrete

I want to create look of giant poured in place pavers on my driveway, using the existing concrete slab. Other than cutting all the way thru the slab and removing giant lines of concrete, then refilling it to desired depth, is there an easier way to do this? I want 3-4” grooves between pavers for that fake turf grass. Don’t think I need more than 1” depth for that. My question is: is there a tool or grinder blade that can cut a wide, shallow channel in concrete that DOESN’T have to be chipped out?

Comment: A company that specialises in diamond drilling may be able to help, consider contacting any in your area.

Comment: This isn't a DIY proposition. It would take an industrial grinder of a very specialized nature to move that much material and leave clean lines. Even sidewalk grinders use a roller that can't cut channels that narrow. You could rent a rolling diamond saw, but you'd have to cut the sides of the channels, then cut many times between. It would take days of constant cutting.

Comment: I think you meant cut channels that wide , even a masonry grinder with a heavy disk will be 1/4” at best. The idea sounds interesting but I doubt it would be realistic and may cause your slab to start breaking on the cut lines. I like thicker driveways but I know quite a few contractors that use a 2x4 so the slab is only 3-1/3 thick. Cut an inch out and now it will break up. If thicker it may hold up.

Answer (score 1):

Put a 1" topping on your slab. Leave 3" grooves out of the topping

Comment: This is probably the easiest solution. BUT it assumes that the slab does not currently butt up against something which cannot afford a one inch rise (foundation with siding) or if the slab transitions into something which is at the height of the original slab (like a driveway).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: Short answer, but I think it's the right concept.  Removing a strip is way too difficult and could harm the structure.  Adding "poured in place pavers" is the best way to get the look of poured in place pavers....